# What's the etymology for the word "business logic" in programing world?

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology

Why it's been called "business logic" but not "main logic" or "important logic" or "core logic"...?

Was it related to "trading" or "commercial" things?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441202/why-is-it-called-business-logic-where-did-this-term-come-from